# how to get data added and deleted from two data frames when compared

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have two dataframes which is data we have is monthly data , in month data can be added and deleted when compared with other month data , i want column added in which added and other deleted.

example june output

```
customer    region
a1           us
a2           us
b1           uk
b3           china
b4           aus
```

Example july output

```
customer    region
a1           us
a2           taiwan
a3           india
b1           uk
b3           china
b4           india
b4           aus
b2           japan
```

output should be

```
  delete region   addedcustomer  detedcus    addedregion
      us                           a1
                     a2                           taiwan
     us              a3                            india
                     b3                             china
                     b4                             india
                     b2                              japan
```

Comment: Please format your question to show your examples as tables and make your example reproducible